# JaperReports. Вычисление параметров для отчета по иерархии географических адресов

Tags: java, sql, jasperreports, jasperstudio

Возникла необходимость реализации следующего отчета на Jasper. 
На вход пользователю необходимо предложить выбрать один или несколько адресных объектов. Это могут быть населенные пункты, улицы или дома. Пользователь выбирает из предложенных текстовых значений. Параметром для SQL запроса будет соответствующий текстовому значению идентификатор или несколько идентификаторов, если выбрано несколько значений. Возникли трудности с реализацией.

Попытаюсь описать имеющуюся адресную картотеку:
В базе данных oracle есть несколько видов таблиц с адресными данными. У каждого адресного объекта есть уникальный идентификатор. Пары текст-id находятся в отдельной таблице. В другой таблице есть соответствие объекта и его типа (по id можно узнать что это область, населенный пункт, улица, дом или квартира). Есть таблицы с указанием, какой объект является дочерним, а который родительским (можно узнать сколько домов на определенной улице, улиц в определенном населенном пункте и тд).

Как пытался сделать я ... Т.к. опыта работы с Jasper немного, то в БД создал таблицу, в которой каждому идентификатору дома соответствовала текстовая строка с адресом вида "Область, населенный пункт, улица, дом". Получилось около 100 000 записей. Как input control выбрал multi-select query, запрос был вида select a.id, a.adr_str from addr_list a. Как value_id выбрано поле id из запроса, как visible column выбрано поле addr_str из запроса. В таком варианте все устраивает, кроме долгого ожидания окна со вводом параметров при запуске отчета, т.е. Jasper при запуске отчета сначала 5 минут формирует весь список из 100 000 адресов. Этот момент всё портит и я не представляю, как можно исправить ситуацию. Буду признателен за подсказки.

Есть мысль запрашивать у пользователя несколько параметров, т.е. сначала предлагать выбрать область, затем населенный пункт, после улицу и дом. В этом варианте совершенно не понимаю, как можно передать выбранное в одном запросе значение в другой запрос, чтоб вычислить идентификатор или несколько идентифкаторов, которые уже будут параметрами SQL запроса.

Comment: В двух словах, на ДжасперСервере делаете ИнпутКонтролы в которых пишите эти кусочки SQL кода по выбору подкатегорий. Подробнее щас не вспомню

Comment: согласен, только не понятно, как потом передать значение, выбранное в одном input control в другой inputcontrol

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону cascading input controls, кажется это так называется (https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-administrator-guide/v60/cascading-input-controls)

Comment: спасибо, кажется именно то, что нужно, через пару часов смогу попробовать. Один момент не понятен - в докуменатции используются single select query. Интересно - можно ли аналогичным обазом использовать multi-select query? Чтоб пользователь мог выбирать добавлять несколько объектов разных уровней как параметры.

Comment: Возможность такая скорее всего должна быть. Рад помочь. Если получится, разместите это как ответ? )

Comment: обязательно размещу! но пока не понятна возможность использовать multi select query вместо single select query, описанного в документации

Comment: Пока не получается. В отчет мне нужно передать id(1 или несколько) cтроения, а чтобы его вычислить - используется id улицы, список улиц отображается через multi select query. Не понимаю - нужно ли добавлять в отчет оба параметра build_id и street_id, или достаточно только build_id? В любом случае, пока не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании контрола предлагается ввести его имя, и это значение будет в дальнейшем являться его resource_id. В дальнейшем имя можно изменять, а вот resource_id остается постоянным и этот resource_id обязательно должен совпадать с именем параметра в SQL запросе. В моем случае они были разные.